# Why does Swift give me an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION here?

Tags: swift, swift2

When executed in the playground, the following piece of code causes a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`:

```
func greet(person: [String:String]?, age: Int?) {
    guard let name = person!["name"] where person != nil else {
        return
    }
}

greet(nil, age: nil)
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exclamation mark after `person` unwraps the optional which causes the crash because `person` is `nil`.

When you use optional binding you can omit the explicit checking for `nil`.

```
func greet(person: [String:String]?, age: Int?) {
  guard let name = person?["name"] else {
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right! That should've been obvious, thank you.